# Why is my image not showing up Fullscreen?

Tags: swift, uiimageview

I have the following problem. I have about 10 different images which are in a view controller. Now I want the image to switch to fullscreen when they are tapped on. I already set the allow user interaction option to yes, and put in the following code i found on this website:

```
import UIKit

class ImageViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBAction func imageTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let imageView = sender.view as! UIImageView
        let newImageView = UIImageView(image: imageView.image)
        newImageView.frame = self.view.frame
        newImageView.backgroundColor = .blackColor()
        newImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        newImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissFullscreenImage:")
        newImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        self.view.addSubview(newImageView)
    }

    func dismissFullscreenImage(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        sender.view?.removeFromSuperview()
    }
```

Does anyone know why my images are not tappable and turning fullscreen?

Comment: If you set a breakpoint or use `print` inside your `imageTapped` function, is it getting called? Your gesture recognizer in your Storyboard (or xib) may not be wired up to it.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? Where can I edit the gesture recognizer?

Comment: Is your gesture recognizer defined in a storyboard/xib, or in code?

Comment: stupid question but....I don't know how to define it......How does it work?

Comment: Did you do `let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(...` in code, or did you drag out a reference to a recognizer in a visual interface editor in either a .storyboard or .xib file?

Comment: Well the above code is all I have for this ViewController? so do I add the let gesture there?

Comment: It sounds like you don't have a gesture recognizer set up to call the `imageTapped` function. You don't get that for free - you have to add it wherever you initially created the image view that you want to be able to tap. You can do it in the same way you add a new tap recognizer to your full screen image view.

Comment: Oh, and the reason I asked about the `@IBAction` is that you only need that if you're connecting a gesture recognizer from interface builder (that's what the visual storyboard editor is called) to your code. It sounds like that might not be what you're doing, in which case you can delete `@IBAction`.

Comment: Thanks! however, I am still not sure what to do here now...

Comment: It's hard to offer more specific advice without seeing more context (e.g. where did the original tappable image view come from?). Read through this and see if you can figure it out. If not, we can continue this in chat: https://www.raywenderlich.com/76020/using-uigesturerecognizer-with-swift-tutorial

Comment: Thank you for you help! it worked I forgot to add the tap gesture from the object library... got it to work now thank you so much!.... Do you know any tutorials online for adding more images in a scroll view?

Comment: I don't. I recommend googling to find out a little about using `UICollectionView`, which is probably your best bet, and then making a new post here if you have specific questions. StackOverflow discourages multi-question posts. Glad the gesture recognizer is working now!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure both the image view have userInteractionEnabled = YES and 
here's an example for what you are trying to do here https://github.com/abhinavsingh77/ImagePreview

Comment: Yes, I already ticked the box for user interaction in the attribute box

Comment: What about numberOfTapsRequired and numberOfTouchesRequired properties of UITapGestureRecognizer ?